# MySQL query slow with subquery

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT `ownExternalContactID`
FROM `sc_users`
WHERE `sc_users`.`id` IN
    ( SELECT `id`
     FROM `sc_users`
     WHERE `ownExternalContactID` IN
         ( SELECT `externalContactID`
          FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
          WHERE `value` IN
              ( SELECT `value`
               FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
               WHERE `externalContactID` IN
                   (SELECT `id`
                    FROM `sc_external_contacts`
                    WHERE `ownerUserID` = "158") ) ) )
  AND `sc_users`.`id` IN
    ( SELECT `ownerUserID`
     FROM `sc_external_contacts`
     WHERE `id` IN
         ( SELECT `externalContactID`
          FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
          WHERE `value` IN
              ( SELECT `value`
               FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
               WHERE `externalContactID` =
                   (SELECT `ownExternalContactID`
                    FROM `sc_users`
                    WHERE `id` = "158") ) ) )
  AND `sc_users`.`id` != "158"
```

It is used for bidirectional address book entry matching, wherein it compares hashed address book entries in the table `sc_external_contact_data`, which it then connects with the tables `sc_external_contacts` and `sc_users`. So far, so good, this query is really fast, and in my particular instance, it returns the entries 359 and 1091.

This is really convenient, so now I know that the external contacts that are relevant have the IDs 359 and 1091. Now, what I wanna do is get their respective hashes, so I can later send them to the client for local matching with the address book. That I do by embedding the upper query into this:

```
SELECT * FROM `sc_external_contact_data` WHERE `externalContactID` IN (/* upper query */)
```

If you are curious what it looks like, it looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
WHERE `externalContactID` IN
    ( SELECT `ownExternalContactID`
     FROM `sc_users`
     WHERE `sc_users`.`id` IN
         ( SELECT `id`
          FROM `sc_users`
          WHERE `ownExternalContactID` IN
              ( SELECT `externalContactID`
               FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
               WHERE `value` IN
                   ( SELECT `value`
                    FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
                    WHERE `externalContactID` IN
                        (SELECT `id`
                         FROM `sc_external_contacts`
                         WHERE `ownerUserID` = "158") ) ) )
       AND `sc_users`.`id` IN
         ( SELECT `ownerUserID`
          FROM `sc_external_contacts`
          WHERE `id` IN
              ( SELECT `externalContactID`
               FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
               WHERE `value` IN
                   ( SELECT `value`
                    FROM `sc_external_contact_data`
                    WHERE `externalContactID` =
                        (SELECT `ownExternalContactID`
                         FROM `sc_users`
                         WHERE `id` = "158") ) ) )
       AND `id` != "158" )
```

And suddenly, the query becomes EXTREMELY slow, and it only returns two entries.

If you run the query like this, however:

```
SELECT * FROM `sc_external_contact_data` WHERE `externalContactID` IN (359, 1091)
```

It's suddenly just as fast as it ought to be, and returns not two, but four entries.

So my question is: what exactly is the difference between these embedded queries, and why is there a speed difference? If the first query gets these IDs so fast, why does using it as a subquery inhibit the performance so much? And why are the results different?

As of this moment, I cannot seem to find any parenthesis matching errors. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a look at the output of EXPLAIN <query> for both queries?

Comment: Ah, no, I haven't actually.